# How to add check box with tick mark action using iTextSharp 5.5.13

Tags: c#, itext

Checkboxes are working properly with cross marks.
But here i want to replace cross mark with tick mark when checkbox checked.

I tried this code using iTextSharp 5.5.13 in C#:

```
document.Open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect;
PdfFormField Field1;

PdfAppearance[] onOff = new PdfAppearance[2];
onOff[0] = cb.CreateAppearance(20, 20);
onOff[0].Rectangle(1, 1, 18, 18);
onOff[0].Stroke();

onOff[1] = cb.CreateAppearance(20, 20);
onOff[1].SetRGBColorFill(255, 128, 128);
onOff[1].Rectangle(1, 1, 18, 18);
onOff[1].FillStroke();
//onOff[1].MoveTo(1, 1);
//onOff[1].LineTo(19, 19);
//onOff[1].MoveTo(1, 19);
//onOff[1].LineTo(19, 1);
//onOff[1].Stroke();
RadioCheckField checkbox1;

for (int i = 0; i < LANGUAGES_gc.Length; i++)
{
    rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(180, 806 - i * 40, 200, 788 - i * 40);
    checkbox1 = new RadioCheckField(writer, rect, LANGUAGES_gc[i], "on");

    checkbox1.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK;

    Field1 = checkbox1.CheckField;
    Field1.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "Off", onOff[0]);
    Field1.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "On", onOff[1]);

    writer.AddAnnotation(Field1);

    cb.BeginText();
    cb.SetRGBColorFill(255, 0, 0);
    cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, false), 8);
    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, LANGUAGES_gc[i], 210, 790 - i * 40, 0);
    cb.EndText();

}

cb = writer.DirectContent;
document.Close();
```

Here i tried this one in code for tick mark `checkbox1.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK;`
But didnt any changes in output

Comment: If you *don't* set the appearances to your customized ones (i.e. remove the `Field1.SetAppearance` lines), you'll see tick marks.

Comment: @mkl Thank you sir for your response. Now its working fine(i.e.Tick mark) but there is a small problem, checkbox border is disappeared now.

Comment: Ok, in that case you need your own appearances but draw a tick into it.

Comment: Sir can you have a code please. I didn't understand how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code explicitly sets the appearance of the check boxes by setting the appearance streams to `onOff[0]` and `onOff[1]` respectively. These appearances are used at least when the check box has the focus.

To consistently show a tick, therefore, you have to not only set the `CheckType` but also to adapt your custom appearances or drop them altogether.

You can e.g. adapt your appearances, in particular the **On** appearance, like this:

```
onOff[1] = cb.CreateAppearance(20, 20);
onOff[1].SetRGBColorFill(255, 128, 128);
onOff[1].Rectangle(1, 1, 18, 18);
onOff[1].FillStroke();
onOff[1].BeginText();
onOff[1].SetGrayFill(0);
onOff[1].SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.ZAPFDINGBATS, BaseFont.WINANSI, false), 15);
onOff[1].MoveText(4, 5);
onOff[1].ShowText("4");
onOff[1].EndText();
```

Additionally you have to be consistent concerning the name of your desired active state. Currently you call it "on" in one place

```
checkbox1 = new RadioCheckField(writer, rect, LANGUAGES_gc[i], "on");
```

and then "On" in another

```
Field1.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "On", onOff[1]);
```

You will have to decide whether you want **on** or **On**.

Comment: Yeah , Thank you sir i got it.